# Area under $x=-\sqrt{y}+1$ inside the circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=2$

Tags: integration, area

I have to evaluate the area under $x=-\sqrt{y}+1$ inside the circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=2$.

I know the curves has an intersection at $y=1$. I'm trying to use polar coordinates since the cartesian ones are not useful here.

As the angle is in the range
$$\left[\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi\right]$$
I'm just missing the radius. But as the curve of $y=-\sqrt{y}+1$ is not a line, I don't know how to find it.

Comment: "... the cartesian ones are not useful here." What would make you say that?

Comment: Try shifting everything left by 1 unit

Answer (score 1):

The equation of parabola is $y = (x-1)^2$ and the equation of circle is $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 2$

Translation of coordinates does simplify the work.
$X = x-1, Y = y$. $|J| = 1$.

As you need to find area under the parabola and inside the circle, we are looking for area bound by
$~Y \leq X^2, X^2 + Y^2 \leq  2$. Intersection points are $(-1, 1)$ and $(1, 1)$. See the shaded region in the sketch.

[image]

As there is symmetry about y-axis, we can find area for $x \geq 0$ and multiply by $2$.

In polar coordinates, $Y \leq X^2 \implies r \geq \sec\theta \tan\theta$
$X^2 + Y^2 \leq 2 \implies r \leq \sqrt2$

For $~-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq 0, 0 \leq r \leq \sqrt2$
For $~0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4, \sec\theta \tan\theta  \leq r \leq \sqrt2$

Another approach will be to find

i) the area above  parabola and below line $Y = 1$ using cartesian coordinates.

$X^2 \leq Y \leq 1, -1 \leq X \leq 1$

ii) the area of the circle above $Y = 1$ using polar coordinates,

$\csc\theta \leq r \leq \sqrt2, \pi/4 \leq \theta \leq 3\pi/4$

Then subtract $(i) + (ii)$ from total area of the circle, which is $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume you want the angle in range $\left[\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right]$ but instead, let me give your statements in explicit forms:

$f(x)=x^2-2x+1$ is equal to your function in $[0,1]$ and we'll not evaluate for $x>1$.

$g(x)=\sqrt{-x^2+2x+1}$ is equal to the semicircle in the positives, and likewise

$h(x)=-\sqrt{-x^2+2x+1}$.

The area you are looking for is composite of the two integrals in the intervals $[1-\sqrt2, 0]$ between $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ and $[0,1]$ between $f(x)$ and $h(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the appearance of $x-1$ in each term (as $x - 1 = -\sqrt{y}$ in the first equation), I recommend first translating the region by $1$ unit in the $x$ direction; now the desired region is bound by $x = -\sqrt{y}$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 2$. Now it is easier to use polar coordinates, as in the latter case $r \leq \sqrt{2}$ and in the former case $r \cos \theta = -\sqrt{r \sin \theta}$ or equivalently $r = - \sec \theta \tan \theta$.

Question: are you specifically integrating over $x \leq 1$ (in the new coordinates, $x \leq 0$)? Because the $\sqrt{y}$ term is just one branch of a whole parabola, and there is therefore not an immediately clear "underside" for $x > 1$ (in the new coordinates, $x > 0$).